# Basic understanding of JMH Benchmark

Tags: java, spring, benchmarking, jmh

I have such spring class:

```
@Component
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class CalculatorImpl implements Calculator {

    public CalculatorImpl() {
        System.out.println("Phase 1");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @Benchmark
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Phase 2");
    }
}
```

I added [required maven dependencies and plugin](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-archetypes/jmh-java-benchmark-archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml) and run it with:

```
java -jar target/benchmarks.jar
```

And my "Phase 2" printing goes to infinite loop. Basically, I just want helloworld example. What have I done wrong? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `hello world` example here 
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/7a25c71b43bf/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_01_HelloWorld.java

I suppose, that in you case you got not infinite loop but very long invocation possibly limited or timeouted by speed of print line on your terminal.
Try to benchmark empty method first.